# How to apply the lumo theme inside a shadow dom of custom components in Vaadin Flow

Tags: themes, vaadin, styling

**Is there a recommended way or best practice to apply the css rules of "global" default or custom themes to the shadow root of custom components created with a lit template?**

There is a workaround with a connectedCallback to manually apply the theme with an imported "applyTheme()" function. Another description of the issue and the workaround[see here](https://github.com/vaadin/hilla/issues/273#issuecomment-1058987768)

I have also found a [ticket](https://github.com/vaadin/hilla/issues/273), with some sort of solution, but i just can't figure out how to use this to solve my issue.

That workaround doesn't seem to work when working with the Vaadin Designer plugin in intellij, as it doesn't seem to be able to use the "applyTheme()" function (unresolved import of "import { applyTheme } from frontend/generated/theme"). Also i'd like to avoid this workaround where possible.

If there is another solution than using the mentioned workaround, does it also work with custom themes / changed values of lumo css properties?

Example:

You create a custom component based on a lit template like this:

```
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-horizontal-layout';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-select';
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import {applyTheme} from "Frontend/generated/theme";

@customElement('stub-view-card')
export class StubViewCard extends LitElement {
  //commented this, so we DO use a shadow root   
  /*createRenderRoot() {
    // Do not use a shadow root
    return this;
  }*/
  
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    // Apply the theme manually because of https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11160
    //this is not needed, if no shadow root like above is used
    applyTheme(this.renderRoot);
  }

  render() {
    return html`<li class="bg-contrast-5 flex flex-col items-start p-m rounded-l">
      <div
        class="bg-contrast flex items-center justify-center mb-m overflow-hidden rounded-m w-full"
        style="height: 160px;"
      >
        <img id="image" class="w-full" />
      </div>
      <span class="text-xl font-semibold" id="header"></span>
      <span class="text-s text-secondary" id="subtitle"></span>
      <p class="my-m" id="text"></p>
      <span theme="badge" id="badge"></span>
      <slot></slot>
    </li> `;
  }
}
```

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxRZN.png)

[how it looks like without the connectedCallback and applyTheme()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGMf1.png)

I am using Vaadin 23 and a project generated from [vaadin starter](https://start.vaadin.com/app). My example was created from the "image list"-template.

I really appreciate any help and documentation that you can point me to :)

Comment: `applyTheme` is the correct solution to this use case. Not sure why that import is unresolved for you, though. One reason could be that your app does not have a custom theme. Without a custom theme, I think `applyTheme` is not generated. Also, you need to run the app at least once to have it generated.

Comment: @Jouni thanks for clarification about the usage of applyTheme. About the custom theme: I have just added some values for the custom lumo properties in the styles.css - which works fine, as long as i have disabled the Vaadin Designer plugin. Once i enable it, it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Sounds like this might be a bug with Vaadin Designer then, the way it handles custom themes.

Comment: Oh, well, looks like it is a long-standing bug, unfortunately: https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2413